# Popup window not working while clicking on button

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm creating as simple popup I don't know where I've done wrong but I'm getting only the background color which i have mentioned in the style tags not the content on popup. I've mentioned/linked the script file and css file in the code. Please help me out with this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        
        $('a.default').click(function(){
            
            var popupbox = $(this).attr('href');
            $(popupbox).fadeIn(400);
            
            var popMargTop = ($(popupbox).height()+24)/2;
            var popMargLeft = ($(popupbox).width()+24)/2;
            $(popupbox).css({
                'margin-top': -popMargTop,
                'margin-left': -popMargLeft
            });
            $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
            $('#mask').fadeIn(400);
            return false;
        });
        
        
        $('a.close, #mask').on('click', function(){
            $('#mask, .popupinfo').fadeOut(400, function(){
                $('#mask').remove();
            });
        });
    });
    
        $(document).keyup(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 27){
                $('mask, .popupinfo, #popup-box').fadeOut(400);
                return false;
                
            }
        })
```

```css
body {
            background: #e2e2e2;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .popupinfo {
        display: none;
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #1852fd;
            float: left;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
            z-index: 99999;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #1852fd;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #1852fd;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #1852fd;
            border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        }
        #mask {
            display: none;
            background: #9ACD32;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 88888;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 0.9;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clearfix">
        <a class="btn btn-circle btn-sm default">
            Open <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
     
     <div id="popup-box" class="popupinfo">
        <form>
            <label>This can be anything</label><br>
         <input type="text" name="random" /><br>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-circle btn-sm close">
                Close <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </a>
        
         
         
         </form>
     
      </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: missing jquery.add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`in your heading `tag`.It should work.

Comment: This would be much easier to answer with a live sample, say a fiddle or codepen... Also you seem to be missing <head> tags around your style and script (assuming you are trying to put them in the head)

Comment: I've mentioned in the question itself that mandatory file have been included by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've corrected your code, here is the working code:

```js
$(function() { // DOM loaded    

    var openPopup = function(e) { // Function to open the popup
        $(e).fadeIn(400);
        $('#mask, .popupinfo').fadeIn(400);
    };    

    var closePopup = function() { // Function to close the popup
        $('#mask, .popupinfo').fadeOut(400);
    };    

    $('a.default').click(function(e) {
    
        e.preventDefault();
        var popupbox = $(this).attr('href');
        openPopup(popupbox);
        
        var popMargTop = ($(popupbox).height()+24)/2;
        var popMargLeft = ($(popupbox).width()+24)/2;
        $(popupbox).css({
            'margin-top': -popMargTop,
            'margin-left': -popMargLeft
        });
    });    

    $('a.close, #mask').on('click', function() {
        closePopup();
    });
    
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            closePopup();
        }
    });    

});
```

```css
body {
    background: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #fff;
}

.popupinfo {
   display: none;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #1852fd;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
    z-index: 99999;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #1852fd;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #1852fd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #1852fd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#mask {
    display: none;
    background: #9ACD32;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 88888;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mask"></div>

<div class="clearfix">
    <a href="#popup-box" class="btn btn-circle btn-sm default">
        Open <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </a>
</div>

 <div id="popup-box" class="popupinfo">
    <form>
        <label>This can be anything</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="random" /><br>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-circle btn-sm close">
            Close <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help but its not disappearing while pressing the esc button or clicking outside the popup window

Comment: clicking outside the popup window to disappear

Comment: You hardcoded `#popup-box` in popup open event, so it cannot be used as common feature for different anchors with different popups

Comment: @GeneR, you are right, I fixed the hard coded ID into the href attribute as in your solution.

Comment: @NitishKumar, JS code refactored for a more modular approach. Added clicking outside the popup feature.

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot.

Comment: Hi Artifex404, I want to hide the open button when popup box opens, any idea how can we do it?

Comment: @NitishKumar, just add the button hiding call in the openPopup() function. Make sure to show the button again in the closePopup() function.

Comment: Thanks for the help but its coming up whenever I'm clicking anywhere even in the popup box, i want to restrict coming up while clicking it on popupbox or hide until popbox is not closed.

Comment: Hey can you help me with this??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097764/content-editable-cursor-position-to-be-in-editable-div-when-popup-of-text-editor

Answer (score 1):

Add `href="#popup-box"` to anchor that opens popup:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <a class="btn btn-circle btn-sm default" href="#popup-box">
        Open <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/gewibibule/edit?html,output

Also missing `#` here before `mask`:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
        $('#mask, .popupinfo, #popup-box').fadeOut(400);
        return false;

    }
})
```